# How to perform multiple AND statement after THEN Statement

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Crons()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim check1 As Boolean, check5 As Boolean, check10 As Boolean, flow As Boolean, speed As Boolean, motor_power As Boolean
    
    Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set s2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    
    check1 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 1").Value = xlOn
    check5 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 5").Value = xlOn
    check10 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 10").Value = xlOn
           
    flow = s1.Range("B26").Value = "Flow(from fill level)"
    speed = s1.Range("B24").Value = "Speed"
    motor_power = s1.Range("B25").Value = "Motor Power"
    
    If check1 Or _
        ((check10 Or check5) Or _
        (flow Or speed) Or _
        (motor_power)) Then
            s1.Range("B30").Value = "Activate anomaly detection" And _
            s1.Range("B31").Value = "Activate Operating hour" And _
            s1.Range("B32").Value = "Activate cycle time"
    Else
        s1.Range("B30").Value = vbNullString And _
        s1.Range("B31").Value = vbNullString And _
        s1.Range("B32").Value = vbNullString
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use `AND`!

```
If check1 Or _
    ((check10 Or check5) Or _
    (flow Or speed) Or _
    (motor_power)) Then
        s1.Range("B30").Value = "Activate anomaly detection" 
        s1.Range("B31").Value = "Activate Operating hour"
        s1.Range("B32").Value = "Activate cycle time"
Else
    s1.Range("B30").Value = vbNullString 
    s1.Range("B31").Value = vbNullString 
    s1.Range("B32").Value = vbNullString
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the `And` operator. It has two purposes:

- A logical operator, similar to the `Or` you've used in your `If` statement. Whereas `True Or False` equals `True`, `True And False` equals `False`.
- A bitwise operator, taking two integer operands and returning a value consisting of the `1` bits present in both operands. For example, `14 And 7` = binary `1110 And 0111` = binary `0110` = 6.

Trying to use it as a procedural statement ("do X, and then do Y") per your code is not only incorrect but makes no sense, since this is the ordinary behaviour of two statements in sequence.